# Why Checkbox is not getting bound to data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, webforms

I am picking a BIT field from database's table via SP and using it to fill gridview. All fields are fine in gridiview except Checkbox field which doesn't represent boolean data from database. It remains UnTicked instead of getting Ticked incase of TRUE value

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Conveyed ?">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxIsConveyed" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkBoxIsConveyed_CheckedChanged" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsConveyed")) %>' AutoPostBack="true" /> 
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

.cs:

```
protected void chkBoxIsConveyed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent).DataItemIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this:

```
 Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsConveyed")).ToString() == "1" ? true : false
```

To this:

```
 Checked=<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsConveyed")) %>
```

Comment: correct...:( please try my update and let me know. Thanks

Comment: ok sir working but it's only one way, mean it shows what is in database but upon unticking it doesn't get updated in DB

Comment: @Juventustech In order to update the corresponding field in your database, you have to POST you change to the server. By simply checking or unchecking a checkbox, without making a POST, nothing changes.

Comment: but I am using CHeckChanged event, but that doesn't get fired, :/

Comment: it has tired me, the event doesn't get fired, it have an update code inside that but doesn't get updated

Comment: In the code you have posted, I don't see this. You should have something like this: `<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" ...OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged"/>`

Comment: yes sir, i did now. and set autopostback= true but event doesn't get fired

Comment: Hm...something is strange here.  Honestly I can't help you, If I don't see the whole relevant code. I suggest your edit your question and place there all the relevant code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97333/discussion-between-christos-and-juventus-tech).